# why i am getting the error while concatenating multiple csv file in one csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df=pd.read_csv("./Sales_data/Sales_April_2019.csv")
files=[file for file in os.listdir("./Sales_data")]
all_months_data=pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    df=pd.read_csv("./Sales_data/"+file)
    all_months_data=pd.concat([all_months_data , df])
   
all_months_data.head()
```

getting below error while concatenating **12 excel file** in one file csv file

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './Sales_data/.ipynb_checkpoints'
```

concatenating multiple **csv file on one csv file**

Comment: Are you sure that in that folder you have only excel files not others?

Answer (score 2):

You should restrict the files to csv files, for example using `glob`:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

df = pd.read_csv("./Sales_data/Sales_April_2019.csv")

files = glob("./Sales_data/*.csv")
all_months_data=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]+[df])
    
all_months_data.head()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help now the code is executed successfully , and sry this time i cant buy a coffee for you sorry